# UITableView падает с NSRangeException

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit

Здравствуйте! Есть у меня свой клас которий я наследую от UITableViewController вот примерний код:

```
 @interface MovieViewController ()
        {
            NSMutableArray *movies;
        }

 @end

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //check interned connection
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(status != NotReachable && movies == nil)
    {
        [self loadMovies];
    }
    else if(movies != nil)
    {
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error:"
                                           message: @"Cant connect to movieDB!"
                                          delegate: self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(void)loadMovies
{
    movies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if([self.title isEqualToString:@"TopView"])
    {
        [Movie topRatedWithCallback:^(NSMutableArray *result)
         {
             movies = result;
             [self.tableView reloadData];
         }];
    }
...
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [movies count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"MovieCell";
    MovieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MovieCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    Movie *movie;
    @try {
        movie = movies[indexPath.row];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Exception:"
                                                        message: [exception reason]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    cell.titleView.text = movie.movieTitle;
    cell.ID = movie.ID;

    return cell;
}
```

Проблема в том что если поскролить некоторое время таблицу,  а потом выбрать ячейку то выкидывает исключение типа NSRangeException. Почему? Таблица является табом для таб бар контролера. Может когда я переключаю табы то масив movies изменяется?

Comment: а что в информации NSRangeException ? что в стеке, в каком методе exception возникает?